# How to replace the text with not containing specific string with the same line?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Input text file: file.txt

```
AAA
BBB_CCC
BBB
AAA BBB
```

Need to get:

```
AAA_CCC
BBB_CCC
BBB_CCC
AAA_CCC BBB_CCC
```

I call the sed with following regexp:

```
sed "/_CCC/! s/AAA/AAA_CCC/g;/_CCC/! s/BBB/BBB_CCC/g" file.txt > file_out.txt
```

But it produces:

```
AAA_CCC
BBB_CCC
BBB_CCC
AAA_CCC BBB
```

One solution is calling sed twice on the same file, but I think there exists a more elegant way.

Comment: Do you want to append `_CCC` to every field or just to fields `AAA` and `BBB`? In other words, what if you have field `DDD`, or what if you have field `BBB_CCC_BBB`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way consists to overwrite `_CCC` systematically if it exists:

```
sed 's/\(AAA\|BBB\)\(_CCC\)\?/\1_CCC/g' file
```

Using ERE:

```
sed -E 's/(AAA|BBB)(_CCC)?/\1_CCC/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` solution that will append `_CCC` to every field that doesn't contain it:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if( $i !~ /_CCC$/ ) $i = $i"_CCC"; }1' file

#output:
AAA_CCC
BBB_CCC
BBB_CCC
AAA_CCC BBB_CCC
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution that's close to yours in spirit:

```
$ sed -E '/_CCC/!s/(AAA|BBB)/\1_CCC/g' infile
AAA_CCC
BBB_CCC
BBB_CCC
AAA_CCC BBB_CCC
```

Your solution fails because after inserting `_CCC` on the last line, the `/_CCC/!` check fails: the string is now there after all. My solution avoids that problem by using just a single substitution command.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS=' +|\n' '{sub("(_CCC|)$","_CCC"); ORS=RT}1' file

AAA_CCC
BBB_CCC
BBB_CCC
AAA_CCC BBB_CCC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another sed solution:

```
$ sed 's/\(_CCC\)*\( \|$\)/_CCC\2/g' file
AAA_CCC
BBB_CCC
BBB_CCC
AAA_CCC BBB_CCC
```